# User permissions; JSON-string or DB Table?

Tags: php, mysql, json, permissions

I am currently working with a medium-sized team developing a custom content management system for a large client. The CMS is written using PHP and follows the MVC pattern (custom). It is a modular system, for which plugins can be added to the system by us or other developers at a later stage.

The system will contain user-based permissions, and a series of generic roles that have predefined permissions. It is required that a super-admin user can also modify permissions on a user basis (for example John Doe might be defined as a regular user, but has the possibility of modifying content).

Opinion is currently divided about the best way for us to store and handle these permissions. Half of the dev team are suggesting to add a new DB table that will store key/value pairs and user IDs for each user, with boolean values stored in each record. The table structure would be something like this:

```
user_ID: the ID of the user
perm_name: the name of the permission
perm_value: a boolean value dictating whether the user can carry out this action
```

The proposal is that if the value associated with a particular permission is set to `0`, or does not exist in the table, the user does not have the required permission.

The other half of the dev team is favouring storing the permissions in a single field as a JSON-encoded string within the `users` table. So for example, we would store the following JSON for John Doe):

```
{  
    'modifyProducts': 1,
    'addProducts': 1,
    'addPages': 0
}
```

We would then be able to use `json_decode()` within the `User` class to extract the permissions, for example:

```
$this->permissions = json_decode($dbval);
```

I am personally leaning towards the latter option for two main reasons:

1. It is scalable
2. It does not require us to modify the database if we need a new permissions.

In short, what is the best approach for such an application?

Comment: Do you think you'll need to query the tables to find out which users can access a certain module? If not, I think saving the permissions as JSON string would be fine. But you might want to make sure it doesn't grow exponentially in terms of size.

Comment: No. We won't need to be query the table to find the user's permissions in that way. My only concern was about the growth of a JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution in this case would be to use NoSQL database, such as MongoDB - this way you can still keep the scalability and take advantage of the JSON structure.

On the other hand, depending on your `user` table you could take possible advantage of column type indexing and optimize your requests for querying and reading, if of course you're working with normalized database.

I personally would store JSON within a relational DB only when I want to directly display the info and not use it for any querying. Just like you've said yourself - there's always the possibility of ending up with huge and growing JSON string and this would most probably cause troubles at some point.